# Is there any repository containing the framework.jar files for different AOSP versions?

Tags: android, android-source

I have some time/space limitations so I was hoping to not have to build AOSP from scratch in order to generate the framework.jar.

Does anyone know of a repository containing the framework.jar files for different AOSP versions?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

It hosts framework.jar from 11-30 in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17oMwQ0xBcSGn159mgbqxcXXEcneUmnph)